# How to do a loop that takes into account each day of a specific month?

Tags: python, loops

got a weird one i can not figure out how to solve

basically i have to run a section of code, this code extracts data from a file, which name is the format `year-month-day-hour-00-00-consensus`

so what i am trying to do is complete a loop that after the code runs adds an hour then once it gets to midnight adds a day etc, however while i have this working, i can not figure out how i can do this for the months as if it was easy as all months being 30 days for example this would be simple, i am having issues defining the length of days in the month, does any one have any ideas ?

this is the code so far :

```
def calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y):

    if h < 24:

        if d < 10:
            d = "0"+str(d)
        if h < 10:
            h = "0"+str(h)
        if m < 10:
            m = "0"+str(m)

        consensus_file_name = str(y) + "-" + str(m) + "-" + str(d) + "-" + str(h) + "-00-00-consensus"
        print consensus_file_name 


..... do stuff ....

        h = int(h) + 1 
    else:
        h = 00
        d = int(d) + 1
            #   d = d + 1
```

i pre set this by :

```
h = 00 #Hour
d = 01 #Day
m = 10 #Month
y = 2013 #Year

calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)

# def run_calculate(h,d,m,y):
#   if m == 02:
#       if d == 28:
#           calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
```

i want to start at 2013-10-01 and end at the present day, how can i achieve this ? sorry if it is a bit confusing but struggle on explaining what i want it to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Python has a `datetime` module that will handle this for you. You make a `datetime` object representing the date and time, and a `timedelta` object to represent the addition of 1 hour. You can then, if you need to, check whether the new date is within the same day as the original date by comparing the `.day` property of the `datetime` object.

`datetime` also has a convenient method [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for printing formatted output based on the date and time.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y):
    before = datetime(hour = h, day = d, month = m, year = y)
    now = before + timedelta(hours = 1)
    if before.day == now.day:
        print 'still the same day'
        # ... do stuff ...
    else:
        print "now it's a different day"
        # ... do other stuff ... 
    print now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-00-00-consensus')    

h = 00 #Hour
d = 01 #Day
m = 10 #Month
y = 2013 #Year
calculate_and_write_hsdir(h, d, m, y)
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be what i am after, but how do i achieve the increase of an hour each time ?

Comment: `now = before + timedelta(hours = 1)` does that. You may want to keep track of the time by storing `now` as a global variable (instead of h, d, m, y) or have `calculate_and_write_hsdir` return `now` when it terminates.