# weird issues with an IF loop

Tags: python, loops

i am having a weird issue with my if loop this is the code below :

```
def run_calculate(h,d,m,y):
    if m == 01:
        while True:
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 31:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1
                    y = y

    if m == 02:
        while True:
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 28:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1

    if m == 03:
        while True:
            print "In MARCH LOOP"
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 31:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    print "March Done"
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1
```

basically what i am trying to do is run the calculate_and_write_hsdir each time for every hour of the day, after it does 24 hours it returns d (day) icremented by 1

what i am trying to do is stop it as it gets to the end of the month, however if i start it off at say jan 25 it will work fine untill feb 29 where it crashed, but if i start it off at feb 01 it crashes at on feb 29 too

what am i doing wrong ?

here is how i am starting it

```
h = 00 #Hour
d = 28 #Day
m = 8 #Month
y = 2013 #Year

run_calculate(h,d,m,y)
run_calculate(00,01,01,2014)
run_calculate(00,01,01,2015)
```

Comment: It should stop at the end of feb 28, and start on march, but now it is crashing on feb 29, as it is not ending and starting on march

Comment: why you use `01` and why not `1` ? leading zero means ith Octal number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053892/how-to-do-a-loop-that-takes-into-account-each-day-of-a-specific-month

Comment: This looks like a more basic problem of not understanding flow control.  Your code needs `break`s to stop the `while` loops.  Otherwise, it will stay in the first `while True` it encounters.

Comment: How did it crash? Since you don't break out of the `while` loop its likely that something inside `calculate_and_write_hsdir` is causing a problem when its paramters get too big. Looking at the actual crash would give you insight into that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your while loop will not end because of your if statement. You need to make sure you stop executing your current block when your done. You could also add a break;

```
def run_calculate(h,d,m,y):
    if m == 01:
        while d <= 31:
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 31:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1
                    y = y

    if m == 02:
        while d <= 28:
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 28:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1

    if m == 03:
        while d <= 31:
            print "In MARCH LOOP"
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 31:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    print "March Done"
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if m == x` are outside of the `while True` loops.

So when you start with `m=1`, you iterate until `d=31` and then pass to `m=2` **in same loop**. So you try to iterate again until `d == 31` that's why program breaks at feb 29.

You should write instead :

```
def run_calculate(h,d,m,y):
    while True:
        if m == 01:
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 31:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1
                    y = y

        if m == 02:
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 28:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1

        if m == 03:
            print "In MARCH LOOP"
            d = calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
            if d == 31:
                    calculate_and_write_hsdir(h,d,m,y)
                    print "March Done"
                    d = 01
                    m = m + 1
```

to be sure to pass into the correct branch of the `if`.